# get data from each td in html table and pass it to controller

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have html table in my purchase order form which is dynamically generated. So I want to fetch data from each row of that table and save it to database. This is what I tried...

```
  $('#submit').click(function(){
  var TableData = new Array();
  $('#cart_details tr').each(function(row, tr){
    alert(row+ tr);
   TableData[row]={
    "productname" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
    , "quantity" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
    , "unit" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
    , "unit_rate" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
  }
    alert(TableData);
});
var obj=JSON.stringify(TableData);

 var followurl='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/purchase/save_product";?>';
 $.post( followurl, {'obj' : obj}, function(data){
    alert(obj);
        alert(data);



            }); 

});
```

Here I am calling this function on submit of form and cart_details is the id of table. productname and quantity,unit,unit_rate are the column names of table.

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: How do I get html table data??

Comment: Where do you define the `TableData` variable? What makes you think that your current code doesn't work? Does it produce an error?

Comment: it doesnt produce error but it not getting what I want. When I alert tabledata, that alert is not coming...

Comment: your code looks correct to me.do console.log(TableData); to see data in console .alert wont help because you have created objects.

Answer (score 0):

see this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var TableData=[];//declare your array
    $('#submit').click(function(){
          $('#cart_details tr').each(function(row, tr){
            alert(row);
           TableData[row]={
            "productname" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
            , "quantity" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
            , "unit" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
            , "unit_rate" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
          }
            alert(JSON.stringify(TableData));
            console.log(TableData);//output [Object { productname="1", quantity="2", unit="3", more...}]
        });

        });

});


<table id="cart_details">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">click</button>
```

Comment: @KedarB what you want in output.see the logged value in console.

Comment: When I alert tabledata it display this...[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: I want that whole data in table and want to save it to the database.

Comment: that is what i'm saying do console.log it will show the data.alert directly can not parse object.

Comment: i have updated in answer use  alert(JSON.stringify(TableData)); to see data in alert.

Comment: ok.. I got all data in alert but I want to save it to database.

Comment: then make an ajax call and loop through the data to insert in table.

Comment: always try to use console.log to see data use alert for messages only.

Comment: see a simple ajax demo here:http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp use type : "post", in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68068/discussion-between-suchit-kumar-and-kedar-b).